# display incoming call after receiving fcm notification in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, incoming-call

i'm using callkeep and react native with firebase, i want to show incoming call or wake app up when receiving incoming push from fcm when app is closed(quieet state). so i already tried to show incoming call or backToForeground, but it not works for my device with android 11 in headless mode?

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
//1
RNCallKeep.backToForeground();
//2
       RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall(
         callId,
         "123",
         "shb",
        "number",
         false,
         {
           supportsDTMF: true,
           supportsHolding: true,
        }
       );
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

the setup of call keep happens when getting permission in some sliding/next senario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of android you must configure the permissions to be able to show the call window, you can do it in the following way.

```
  const options = {
    android: {
      alertTitle: 'Permissions Required',
      alertDescription: 'This application needs to access your phone calling accounts to make calls',
      cancelButton: 'Cancel',
      okButton: 'ok',
    },
  };
  RNCallKeep.setup(options);
```

Also in the displayIncomingCall you can use this configuration, it is the one that works for me currently.

```
RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall(callUuid, callerNumber, callerName, 'number', true);
```

You should also use silent notifications, in case you need help, here is the documentation, it is important that you define the priority of the notification so that it can arrive in the background & quit.

https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#data-only-messages

Comment: thank you for response, but i already tried this way, but it just wont work when app is closed but i can see my log when receiving notif, its fine when app is alive, is it related to window alert permission?

Comment: Sure, I think you need the permission to show it outside the app. Although with the configuration that I showed you, it should be enough.

Comment: unfortunatly inside the background handler we cant use setup, it caused error :(

Comment: It shouldn't, I'm using `displayIncomingCall` inside `setBackgroundMessageHandler` with no problem.

Comment: did you used set up inside of handler for each push?

Comment: Yes, the idea would be after receiving the notification, you do your validations and then show the incoming call.

Comment: did you saw this?
https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep/issues/410

Comment: Interesting, it throws me that warning a few times, but I always ignored it. I never thought it was because of RNCallKeep. Did you finally get it to work?

Comment: actually they say ignore it, but it worked after using setup in handler!